# Going from Select Statement to Delete

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-delete

I have this query which I found to get duplicate records:

```
SELECT x.[Constituent Number], x.[First Name], x.[Last or Org Name],x.[Address Line 1], Cnt = Count(*) 
FROM (   
    SELECT SR.[Constituent Number], SR.[First Name], SR.[Last or Org Name], SR.[Address Line 1]
    FROM dbo.['All Salsa Records TL$'] SR

    UNION ALL

    SELECT WD.[Member Number], WD.[First Name], wd.[Last or Org Name], WD.[Address Line 1]
    FROM dbo.['Workling to delete$'] WD
) x
GROUP BY x.[Constituent Number], x.[First Name],x.[Last or Org Name],x.[Address Line 1]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This is between two tables. How would I go about deleting records from the master table to match this queries selected results?

EDIT: I managed to figure it out using this code:

```
DELETE SR
--SELECT SR.[Constituent Number], SR.[First Name], SR.[Last or Org Name]
FROM dbo.['All Salsa Records TL$'] AS SR
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.['Workling to delete$'] WD
    ON WD.[Member Number] = SR.[Constituent Number]
    AND WD.[First Name] = SR.[First Name]
    AND WD.[Last or Org Name] = SR.[Last or Org Name] 
    AND WD.[Address Line 1] = SR.[Address Line 1]
    AND WD.[City]  = SR.[City]
    AND WD.[State] = SR.[State]
WHERE SR.[Constituent Number] = WD.[Member Number]
    AND WD.[First Name] = SR.[First Name]
    AND WD.[Last or Org Name] = SR.[Last or Org Name] 
    AND WD.[Address Line 1] = SR.[Address Line 1]
    AND WD.[City]  = SR.[City]
    AND WD.[State] = SR.[State]
```

For the nulls, I just used this (and changed accordingly as I had 11 records with null constituents and 26 records with null addresses):

```
DELETE SR
--SELECT SR.[Constituent Number], SR.[First Name], SR.[Last or Org Name]
FROM dbo.['All Salsa Records TL$'] AS SR
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.['Workling to delete$'] WD
    ON WD.[Member Number] = SR.[Constituent Number]
    AND WD.[First Name] = SR.[First Name]
    AND WD.[Last or Org Name] = SR.[Last or Org Name] 
    AND WD.[Address Line 1] IS NULL
    AND WD.[City] IS NULL
    AND WD.[State] IS NULL
WHERE SR.[Constituent Number] = WD.[Member Number]
    AND WD.[First Name] = SR.[First Name]
    AND WD.[Last or Org Name] = SR.[Last or Org Name] 
    AND SR.[Address Line 1] IS NULL
    AND SR.[City] IS NULL
    AND SR.[State] IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If ['All Salsa Records TL$'] is your master table and [Constituent Number] is the column against which you want to delete rows then :

```
with cte as(
SELECT x.[Constituent Number], x.[First Name], x.[Last or Org Name],x.[Address Line 1], Cnt = Count(*) 
FROM (   
    SELECT SR.[Constituent Number], SR.[First Name], SR.[Last or Org Name], SR.[Address Line 1]
    FROM dbo.['All Salsa Records TL$'] SR

    UNION ALL

    SELECT WD.[Member Number], WD.[First Name], wd.[Last or Org Name], WD.[Address Line 1]
    FROM dbo.['Workling to delete$'] WD
) x
GROUP BY x.[Constituent Number], x.[First Name],x.[Last or Org Name],x.[Address Line 1]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
delete dbo.['All Salsa Records TL$'] where [Constituent Number]  in (select [Constituent Number] from cte)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this code out for testing!

Comment: Please let me know if you face any difficulties.

Comment: No worries :). I am just doing this for testing and learning purposes so no harm done if I mess up. This data comes from an excel file I have. I ran your query and it deleted out 4,565 records while the joins delete was very close. It was 1 record over the select query of 2,471 records. I'm curious what the cte is deleting that is pushing the records higher. I may have figured it out though. I took a count of grouped together constituent numbers with having a count > 1 and got 2,120. I summed the count in excel and got a sum around 4,248. I'm guessing the original data may have duplicates.

Comment: I have a backup just in case I need to undo.

Comment: if there are multiple rows for a "Constituent Number" then the number of deleted rows will be more then the selection since selection is made based on group by. Do you want to delete exactly those rows? then you need to add all the columns from group by condition.

Comment: something like delete dbo.['All Salsa Records TL$']  all from cte where all.a=cte.a and all.b=cte.b